# "Invalid Argument" exception message on IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection .open method

Tags: c#, ado.net, db2

So I'm getting a fantastically descriptive error message of "Invalid Argument" when trying to hook up to a DB2 database.  I can successfully connect to it using SQUirrel (and JDBC) using the JTopen JDBC driver with the connection string of "jdbc:as400://server;naming=system;errors=full;prompt=no"

Since the jdbc connection works, I know its a Db2.net connector issue.  But the error message "Invalid Argument" frustrates any efforts into diagnosing where to begin.

```
string connStr = "server=server;uid=user;pwd=password";
using(DB2Connection conn=new DB2Connection(connStr))
{
  conn.Open();
  //System.ArgumentException: Invalid argument
  //   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.ReplaceConnectionStringParms(DB2Connection connection, String szValue, DB2ConnSettings& pSettings, DB2ConnSettingsInternal& pSettingsInternal, Boolean bAttach)
  //   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
  //   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection..ctor(String connectionString)
  //   at AuroraDAL_ConnectionTests.DB2ConnectionTests.try1() in C:\Projects\...\DB2ConnectionTests.cs:line 31
  //   at AuroraDAL_ConnectionTests.DB2ConnectionTests.Execute() in C:\Projects\...\DB2ConnectionTests.cs:line 19
  //   at AuroraDAL_ConnectionTests.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Projects\...\Program.cs:line 20
}
```

Using the testconn20.exe within the DB2.net connector program files directory, I tried several options, taking the first connection string above, to then changing the shorthand keys to their longhand values, (uid changed to user id, pwd changed to password, etc)

```
testconn20 server=server;database=database;user id=userid;password=password
```

the result of that returns the same "Invalid Argument" exception eventually:

```
Step 1: Printing version info
        .NET Framework version: 2.0.50727.5448
        64-bit
        DB2 .NET provider version: 9.0.0.2
        Capability bits: ALLDEFINED
        Build: 20090522
        Factory for invairant name IBM.Data.DB2 verified
        Elapsed: 0.089982

Step 2: Connecting using "server=-------;database=------;userid=------;password=------"
Invalid Argument Exception:
        Connection string should be of the type 'Database=db2db; Server=mymachine:60000; User ID=db2user; Password=xxxxxxxx


Test failed.
```

Does anybody with some DB2 and C# have any suggestions as to what i'm doing wrong?  THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that IBMs site doesnt direct you to latest and greatest bits of their .net data connector. The problem was mostly solved by thoroughly looking for updates and finding their  "Fix Central". This is where they keep updates and hot fixes. However it was not easy to get the right package.

Comment: this ended up being the correct answer... the DLLs loaded had bugs that were fixed in "Fix Pack 8" they called it.

Answer (score 1):

I have no DB2 experience, but looking carefully at your code I noticed that you don't specify the Database= and the PortNumber in Server= of your connection string

Comment: yes, thats due to trying to obfuscate the actual server info.  The "easy" stuff I've already pretty much.  Notice how the JDBC driver works without database specified.

Additionally, DB2 is a "special" server, that doesn't seem to need "the database specifier".  In this case the one database IS the server (but I'm a DB2 newbie too, so I'm a little bit skeptical about that)

Answer (score 0):

finally I create the correct connection string:

```
Database=DBNAME;Server=IP:PORT;UID=USERNAME;Pwd=MYPASSWORD;LibraryList=LIBRARYNAME;PersistSecurityInfo=True;
```

For more parameters consult this: DB2Connection.ConnectionString property
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=properties-connectionstring